# Wrong output when multiplying. Is it a bug in my compiler? c++

Tags: c++

When i write this:

```cpp
cout << 10000 * 10000;
```

I get this output:

```cpp
100000000
```

But when I try:

```cpp
cout << 100000 * 100000;
```

I get:

```cpp
1410065408
```

How is this possible? And why?

Comment: 100000*100000 is 10 billion, far above the maximum number you can store in an `int`. try `100000L*100000L`.

Comment: @Zinki A more exact wording would be "far above the maximum number you can store in **your** `int`, as you just demonstrated" ;-).

Comment: @Zinki, if i write `cout << 100000L * 100000L` i get again `1410065408`...

Comment: It seems that your `long` is also only 32bit, try `100000LL` for `long long`

Comment: @Zinki : There are platforms (DSPs for the most part), where `int` is 64 bits (for added giggles, such platforms typically have `sizeof(int) == 1`).

Comment: @MartinBonner really? 1 "[in natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units)" as scientists like to say?

Comment: @YSC: Yes.  All the integral types have the same size.  This makes distinguishing failure of `fgetc` from reading a char with all bits set tricky.  However such implementations usually are free-standing, so don't have `fgetc`.  (Actually, it looks like DSPs only go up to 40 bits - so `long long` would have to be two words - but my point still stands)

Comment: Look at the value of `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Types of both operands are ints, so type of result is also int. You can run the following program to see what is going on

```
cout << 100000LL * 100000LL << endl;
cout << 100000 * 100000 << endl;
cout << 100000LL * 100000LL % (numeric_limits<unsigned int>::max()+1LL) << endl; // +1 accounts for zero
cout << typeid(100000 * 100000).name() << endl;
```

> 10000000000
>   1410065408
>   1410065408
>   int

Note, that adding of `LL` fixes the problem.

Comment: So `ll` comes from `long long`?

Comment: @DeehoroEjkoli right. That makes number to be a `long long` [literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal)

Comment: You should note that integer overflow is undefined behaviour, so it is just a quirk of your implementation that you get 1410065408 (rather than an infinite loop or `rm -rf /`).

Comment: @MartinBonner i updated the answer, i didn't account for zero in the initial edition.

Comment: @MartinBonner you have bigger reputation than me, so i will listen to you regarding `LL` :D

Comment: "Argument from authority" is always a very weak argument - except when it's me of course :-D.

Answer (score 0):

The operands of the multiplication are integral types. As you haven't supplied a suffix on the operands, your compiler will attempt to coerce them into an `int`, and if that fails, a `long int`. With C++11 it will additionally attempt a coercion to a `long long int`. So pre-C++11 your program behaviour could be undefined at this point, but with C++11 both operands can be represented as a `long long int` as that *must* be at least 64 bits.

So the problem is either down to that or the fact that your system doesn't have an integral type large enough to represent that product (which is probably evaluated at compile time). So your program behaviour is undefined.

If you promote one of the arguments to floating point, then the output will be in floating point, albeit with the associated loss of precision (usually about 15 significant figures).

Take a look at `std::numeric_limits` for more details.

Comment: And how should that suffix be added?

Comment: You can do like this.

`const long double MYCONSTANT = 3.0000000L;`

Comment: "So pre-C++11 your program behaviour could be undefined at this point" - no (not if I have understood you correctly).  Even in C++98, 100000 must fit in `signed long` (and actually fits in `int` on almost all implementations).  It's the product that doesn't fit.

Answer (score -1):

It is giving a garbage value because integer type limit is crossed.
Easiest way is to define with double and square it you'll definitely going to have correct answer.